# How to prove the following ineqiulity : $\exp\left(\int_0^t f(s)ds \right) \le 1+ \int_0^t e^{\max(1,s)f(s)}ds$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, integral-inequality, jensen-inequality

> Let $f$ be integrable on $[0, t]$ , $t≥0$ then prove that 
>   $$\exp\left(\int_0^t f(s)ds \right) \le 1+ \int_0^t e^{\max(1,t)f(s)}ds$$

This clearly smells like Jensen's inequality where we instead have, 
$$\exp\left(\frac1t\int_0^t f(s)ds \right) \le \frac1t \int_0^t e^{f(s)}ds$$
I don't see a special function I can plug into the Jensen inequality to get the result.

Does anyone knows how the aforementioned inequality could be derived from Jensen inequality?

Comment: You can use the reversed Bellman inequality (see type 2 here: https://anhngq.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/reversed-gronwalls-inequality/)

Comment: @xpaul it is an exercise given to us by a professor I did not ask him yet.